# Navigation in App: Spinner + ActionBar Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-tabs

I have a problem implementing navigation in my application. I wanted to use `Spinner` like menu, where you can select `item` you interested in and get correspoding data. Then this data will be set to ActionBar tabs.

[image: App]

I've implemented both the spinner and tabs, but one problem occured. Android, doesn't allow to use mutable variables in `OnItemSelectedListener`, while I need it.

```
final ActionBar.Tab tabToday= actionBar.newTab().setText("Today");
final ActionBar.Tab tabSoon = actionBar.newTab().setText("Soon");

..............................

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                switch(arg2){
                case 0:
                    tabToday.setTabListener(new CustomTabListener(MainActivity.this,"item_1", "url"));
                    tabSoon.setTabListener(new CustomTabListener(MainActivity.this,"item_1", "url_2"));
                    
                    actionBar.addTab(tabToday);
                    actionBar.addTab(tabSoon);              
                    break;
                    
                case 1:
                    tabToday.setTabListener(new CustomTabListener(MainActivity.this,"item_2", "url_3"));
                    tabSoon.setTabListener(new CustomTabListener(MainActivity.this,"item_2", "url_4"));

                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                    tabToday.setTabListener(new CustomTabListener(MainActivity.this,"item_3", "url_5"));
                    tabSoon.setTabListener(new CustomTabListener(MainActivity.this,"item_3", "url_6"));
                    break;
                }
        }
```

The problem is that I can't use not `final` variables, and due that this happens:

[image]

is there any way to solve this problem, but remain the same navigation?
Thank you for reading, any help will be appreciated. :)

EDIT:
problem is not in final variables, but issues still remains :((

Comment: Can't you make a final copy of tabToday and tabSoon and use those variables inside the listener like so:
final ActionBar.Tab tabTodayCopy = tabToday. tabToday wouldn't have to be final then.

Comment: tabToday won't be final, but those final copies will go to actionBar. And at the end everything will be the same :(

Comment: Hey could you give a hint How were you able to add tabs and spinner both to your app ? I am facing problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why *final* would be causing that problem but you can avoid using that keyword by not creating an anonymous class by having your activity implement *AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener*

and calling

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: describe class like this `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`
and then implement OnItemSelectedListener inside it? 
If not final variables cause this, what could it be?

Comment: You were right, the problem is not in final Variables :( but now I don't have any idea why that happens

Comment: @AndrewRahimov : hi there, have you find alternative to achieve the goal, i am also looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

Already gone through this problem, where the list will always populating the same data to each interaction. In my case, the problem was when you upgraded the fragment:

```
        if(mFragment==null){
               mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
  /*correct:*/ ft.replace(android.R.id.content,mFragment, mTag);
               ft.add
        }else{
/*correct:*/  ft.attach(mFragment);
        } /*notUse*/ ft.add(mFragment);
```